# "leave for office" or "leave to office"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to know which of these is correct

> When did Rob leave for office?

Or

> When did Rob leave to office?

Comment: leave for *the* office but leave for school or work.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are correct, as you're missing a word. With the word "the" I would expect the former:

> When did Rob **leave for the** office?

You leave *for* somewhere. You can also leave *to do something*:

> When did Rob **leave to** find the office?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of preposition often depends on the particular word (verb or adjective) that governs the phrase; unfortunately there is little logic or pattern to these. So

> *Go* takes a *to* phrase, and can take a *from* phrase
>
> *Come* takes a *from* phrase, and can take a *to* phrase
>
> *Leave* takes a direct object (the place left) and takes a *for* phrase (the destination). It can also take a *from* phrase, typically specifying more precisely than the direct object where the journey starts.
>
> *Arrive* takes an *at* phrase, and can take a *from* phrase

So *When did Rob leave for the office?* is grammatical and natural.

Answer (score 0):

Leave, a verb, means to ***go away*** from someone or something.

We generally may go away to ***do*** something [perform, such as, to skydive, to drive, to play, etc.(***verbs***)] or, ***toward*** something [a location, such as, a country, a park, etc.(***nouns***)]. And, since the object(office) in your example is indeed a noun, the only possible preposition can be `for`.

Thus,

> When did Rob leave for the office?

Yes, the article *the* before *office* is imperative, to signify **that specific place**.

Comment: While your point is correct in your last sentence - _the_ is required - your argument doesn't work. _When did Rob leave for church_ is a specific case, and is quite normal. It isn't the meaning that requires _the_, it's that English syntax requires an article before a singular count noun, apart from some specific exceptions (such as _churcn_).

Comment: With all due respect, Sir, I will have to disagree. For, the example you have cited, _church_, isn't necessarily being directed toward one, "specific" place (a noun), but also hints at a "veiled" verb for the act of praying. Like, the other instances (_school_ & _work_), wherein the **article** isn't required, suggests similar use of logic. As those nouns too, are applied for their actions. The first being for the act of receiving education, and the latter, for performing tasks. Also, the noun, _church_ can have articles associated with it in different situations.

Comment: so you're suggesting that _church_ (and _school_ and _work_) with that meaning becomes an uncountable noun? Maybe: I'll have to think about that.